# ffmpeg run by https URL

Tags: ffmpeg

can I use https://domain/input.mp4 in FFmpeg? for input or output.
I am trying to use it by shell_exec in PHP. but not working.

```
  ffmpeg -i https://domain/input.mp4 -vf scale=1000:1000 -s 500x100 https://domain/output.WMV
```

anyone help me to solve?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if the input is direct link url and the output is on your local machine.

```
wget -O- https://domain/file.mp4 | ffmpeg -i - output.mp4
```